# Using arrayList pointers instead of multiple loops?

Tags: java, loops, oop, pointers, arraylist

I am trying to write a program that contains many classes and in one class called "Dorm",I have an arrayList of Blocks,and in the "Block" class,I have an arrayList of Rooms,and in the "Room" class,I have an arrayList of "Students".
I am trying to access the number of available rooms(the rooms that at least have one empty space) through another class called the "Manager class". I  have been told that I can just create another arrayList in the manager class to be used as a pointer and search up the empty rooms of the whole dormitory.

My question is,how is this going to work?

ps:This is what I wrote:

```html
public static void availableRooms() { //Shows the available rooms in the dormitory.
  
  Dorms dormitory = new Dorms();
     Room room1 = new Room();
  
  for(int i=0;i<dormitory.getBlocks().size();i++)
   for(int j=0;j<Block.getRoomList().size();j++) {
    if(!(room1.getStudentList().get(room1.getRoomCapacity()).equals(null)))
     System.out.print("/t" + room1.getStudentList().get(i) + "/t");
    }
  
  
  
   }
```

My code isn't complete yet,so I'm not sure if it works...

Comment: I think what whoever told you meant that you could keep an ArrayList of empty rooms/spaces in rooms

Comment: Use of a List in a manager class is not clear.  Try this: `Dorm` asks each of its `Block`s how many open spaces are available, a `Block` asks each of its `Room`s how many open spaces are available, and a `Room` reports how many open spaces are available.

Comment: Also, just FYI, you could just use straight arrays here for your Dorms data structure, as # of blocks and rooms and room capacity won't change. But maybe you want to use Lists for Collections support

Comment: @AndrewS This is nit-picky semantics, but where you say "Dorm asks each of its Blocks..." No, these are just data structures. The *controller* uses the data structure API to poll each Dorm and each Block and each Room. It's exactly what you said, except stressing that the business logic should be in the controller, not the data structures

Comment: @ControlAltDel No, in object-oriented programming the objects should be responsible for responding to the requests. The controller should not be aware of the internals of a Dorm or any of its subsidiary objects.

Comment: @DavidConrad My issue is that in a SQL database, you'd more than likely do the object model in reverse. Thinking about how to model in SQL is aside from the question asked, so yes, I am wrong, BUT: In SQL, you'd start with students, who would have a room attribute. The room would have a block, and the block would have a dorm. Then, if you had a table with all the rooms (with max occupancy, block), you could query for rooms   and occupants right from the DB

Comment: @DavidConrad So point (which I didn't make in my first comment) is that this isn't so much an issue of object-oriented vs. non-object oriented. I was trying to make a point about relationship modeling, especially with SQL in mind.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I can add a new block or a new room if I have understood the code correctly.

Comment: @ElenaAsi Code-wise, you could add a new block or a new room, but why would you need to? Look, it's possible that a room gets split in two and then you need to add another room. But a new block? How does that make any sense outside of building a new dorm?

Comment: @ElenaAsi but my other bigger point is about data modeling, and IMO modeling in the opposite direction from the students on down would be superior in a relational database because it would allow the *controller* to query and fetch the data easier. For example, you could take your student database table, and collate by room to get a count of how many students in each room in 1 query. Then you could get the room max occupancy values from the room table. Two queries, rather than having to descend the entire tree like in the way you are modeling it.

Comment: Sorry-by block I meant something like a new building in a campus sort of area.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm pretty new to to java,so I'm not really that informed about data modeling yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share your code/tentative? and clearly specify what's not working?

This being said, unless tied to specific constraints, one should make use of encapsulation and single responsibility principle ([see SOLID on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)) by keeping implementation details private and delegating tasks to the more relevant classes.

You may have something like:

```
class Dorm {
  private List<Block> blocks = ...
  ...
  public int getAvailableRooms() {
      int total = 0;
      for (Block b : blocks) {
        total += b.getAvailableRooms();
      }
      return total;
   }
 }

class Block {
  private List<Room> rooms = ....
  ...
  public int getAvailableRooms() {
    int total = 0;
    for (Room r : rooms) {
      if (! r.isFull()) {
         total++;
      }
    }
}

class Room {
   private int capacity = ...
   private List<Student> students = ..
   ...
   public boolean isFull() {
       return capacity == students.size();
   }
}
```

Where the Manager class, holding (an) instance(s) of Dorm, just make use of the `getAvailableRooms()` method which behind the scene delegate to the underlining Blocks and aggregate result... and so on.